# Repeater, Linkbutton and ModalPopupExtender without postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, repeater

Here's my problem.

I have a repeater. Inside it has lots of textboxes. In the right most column, there is a linkbutton. This link button when clicked will show a modalpopupextender which will display the detail record of the selected row.

I have made it work just fine but its slow because when you click the linkbutton, it will refresh the whole page.

I don't want to reload the repeater because this is the part that is very slow.

I tried adding an updatePanel (repeater inside updatePanel) but ofcourse since the repeater is inside the updatePanel it will still reload the repeater.

So the question is, how do I do it so when the linkbutton is clicked, it wont reload the repeater...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
By the way, I'm developing it with .net 2.0, c#

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this one.

<asp1:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel4" runat="server" >
<ContentTemplate>
 <table id="AssignedRequest" class="tablecont" runat="server" style="width: 900px;" >
 <tr>
   <td>
  <div style=" display:block; width:900px; height:350px;overflow:scroll; ">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepeaterRequest"> 
     <HeaderTemplate >
     <table class="list_table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td><%# Eval("NAME")%></td>

<td><a onclick="window.open(this.href,this.target,'directories=no,
     menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=1,
     status=no,toolbar=no,addressbar=no,fullscreen=yes'); 
     return false;" href="View.aspx?name=<%#Eval("NAME")%>">View</a></td>
</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</table>

</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
</td>
 </tr>
</table>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp1:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Register in the code behind, this code you add it after your bind, for example in your Page_Load,  (You can also use  ItemDataBound or ItemCreated delegate).

```
        rpt.DataBind();
        foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rpt.Items)
        {
            if (ri.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || ri.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                LinkButton lnkButton1 = (LinkButton)ri.FindControl("lnkButton1");
                ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lnkButton1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It throws an error on page load.
A control with ID 'lnkbutton1' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'. 

I am using a repeater not gridview.

Comment: there is a runat=server in my linkbutton.

Comment: id must be correspond, and it's case sensitive

Comment: I copy pasted it so Im sure its same.

Heres a sample of my code. 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkButton1" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <HeaderTemplate>....</HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>....</FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton1" CommandName="details" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("col1") %>' runat="server">Details</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: I do have, on top.. 
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
        <Services>
            <asp:ServiceReference Path="cmDetailService.asmx" />
        </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: Doms i added code to resolve your problem, you find it in code behind and register

Comment: If I add this in code behind do I still need to add <triggers in the updatePanel?

Comment: There is no error now but I think its not working as expected because its still slow.

Is the repeater inside the updatePanel or the modalpopupextender?

Comment: i can't answer to this question , it's difficult for me, modify and compare the best

Answer (score 0):

Why not go for something like a master-child relationship. Do you require further interaction with the child data you are showing to the user? Please specify the nature if so.

Assuming that the child data that you are going to show is simple data meant to simply convey related data to user, you can go for a combination jQuery, and repeaters to accomplish your objective.

The first repeater you show your master data. Against each row in your repeater you show a show button here. You do not need a linkbutton here; just a simple anchor will do. You'd have to write js in it to toggle the correct child data.

All the child data should also be repeated. But not shown to the user at first. Only that particular child item should be shown - this is suitably triggered by the show anchor which is clicked on the master repeater. Rest is all js/css.

Below is a link to a sample project which demonstrates the concept.

http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=2ObqOpjZz0qt7OrXYmmxwA